# HAProxy - Doesn't work from external network

Tags: linux, reverse-proxy, haproxy

I've been digging the internet all night trying to figure out this issue.

So basically I installed a HA Proxy instance to be used as Reverse Proxy.

This is my simple haproxy.conf config:

```
global
        log 127.0.0.1:514       local0 info
        log 127.0.0.1:514       local1 notice
        stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
        maxconn 4096
        user root
        group root
        daemon

defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option forwardfor
        option httplog
        #option dontlognull
        maxconn 2000
        timeout connect 5000
        timeout client 50000
        timeout server 50000

frontend localhost
    log 127.0.0.1:514 local0 debug
    bind *:80
    mode http
    use_backend web1 if { hdr(host) -i shlomitest1.prv.co.il }
    use_backend web1 if { hdr(host) -i shlomitest.prv.co.il }
    use_backend web2 if { hdr(host) -i cba.com }
    use_backend web2 if { hdr(host) -i fed.com }
    default_backend web1

backend web1
    server web1 192.168.30.109:80

backend web2
    server web2 google.com:80
```

HAProxy internal IP: 192.168.30.120

HAProxy External IP: 212.x.x.102 NAT'd to internal

Apache server IP: 192.168.30.109

My workstation internal IP: 192.168.30.102

My workstation External IP: 212.199.xx.xxx

Checkpoint Policy & NAT:

Policy rule -

[image]

NAT rule

[image]

All the packets in the firewall are accepted, none are blocked.
now, there are 2 scenarios:

1. Testing in LAN ( Successfully ):  shlomitest1.prv.co.il pointing to 192.168.30.120.

HAProxy Log:

```
Mar 26 11:37:21 localhost haproxy[14836]: 192.168.30.102:36969 [26/Mar/2019:11:37:21.576] localhost web1/web1 0/0/0/1/1 302 196 - - ---- 1/1/0/1/0 0/0 "GET / HTTP/1.1"
Mar 26 11:37:21 localhost haproxy[14836]: 192.168.30.102:36969 [26/Mar/2019:11:37:21.576] localhost web1/web1 0/0/0/1/1 302 196 - - ---- 1/1/0/1/0 0/0 "GET / HTTP/1.1"
```

TCPDump Log:

```
11:39:56.935968 IP 192.168.30.102.37046 > 192.168.30.120.80: Flags [P.], seq 444:887, ack 197, win 260, length 443: HTTP: GET / HTTP/1.1
11:39:56.936182 IP 192.168.30.120.46226 > 192.168.30.109.80: Flags [S], seq 2799547699, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 13556286 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
11:39:56.936303 IP 192.168.30.109.80 > 192.168.30.120.46226: Flags [S.], seq 3484873804, ack 2799547700, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 467474707 ecr 13556286,nop,wscale 7], length 0
11:39:56.936313 IP 192.168.30.120.46226 > 192.168.30.109.80: Flags [.], ack 1, win 115, options [nop,nop,TS val 13556286 ecr 467474707], length 0
11:39:56.936406 IP 192.168.30.120.46226 > 192.168.30.109.80: Flags [P.], seq 1:453, ack 1, win 115, options [nop,nop,TS val 13556286 ecr 467474707], length 452: HTTP: GET / HTTP/1.1
11:39:56.936461 IP 192.168.30.109.80 > 192.168.30.120.46226: Flags [.], ack 453, win 235, options [nop,nop,TS val 467474707 ecr 13556286], length 0
11:39:56.936952 IP 192.168.30.109.80 > 192.168.30.120.46226: Flags [P.], seq 1:197, ack 453, win 235, options [nop,nop,TS val 467474707 ecr 13556286], length 196: HTTP: HTTP/1.1 302 Found
11:39:56.936957 IP 192.168.30.120.46226 > 192.168.30.109.80: Flags [.], ack 197, win 123, options [nop,nop,TS val 13556286 ecr 467474707], length 0
11:39:56.937045 IP 192.168.30.120.80 > 192.168.30.102.37046: Flags [P.], seq 197:393, ack 887, win 131, length 196: HTTP: HTTP/1.1 302 Found
11:39:57.165921 IP 192.168.30.102.37046 > 192.168.30.120.80: Flags [.], ack 393, win 259, length 0
11:40:01.942176 IP 192.168.30.109.80 > 192.168.30.120.46226: Flags [F.], seq 197, ack 453, win 235, options [nop,nop,TS val 467475958 ecr 13556286], length 0
11:40:01.942268 IP 192.168.30.120.46226 > 192.168.30.109.80: Flags [F.], seq 453, ack 198, win 123, options [nop,nop,TS val 13557537 ecr 467475958], length 0
11:40:01.942394 IP 192.168.30.109.80 > 192.168.30.120.46226: Flags [.], ack 454, win 235, options [nop,nop,TS val 467475958 ecr 13557537], length 0
```

2. Testing from WAN ( Unsuccessful ): shlomitest.prv.co.il pointing to 212.x.x.102.

HAProxy Log:

```
ar 26 11:30:51 localhost haproxy[14836]: 212.199.xx.xxx:55328 [26/Mar/2019:11:30:01.256] localhost localhost/<NOSRV> -1/-1/-1/-1/50002 408 212 - - cR-- 0/0/0/0/0 0/0 "<BADREQ>"
Mar 26 11:30:51 localhost haproxy[14836]: 212.199.xx.xxx:55328 [26/Mar/2019:11:30:01.256] localhost localhost/<NOSRV> -1/-1/-1/-1/50002 408 212 - - cR-- 0/0/0/0/0 0/0 "<BADREQ>"
```

TCPDump Log:

```
11:45:21.216879 IP 212.199.xx.xxx.56486 > 192.168.30.120.80: Flags [S], seq 4078768598, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
11:45:21.216917 IP 192.168.30.120.80 > 212.199.xx.xxx.56486: Flags [S.], seq 169139328, ack 4078768599, win 14600, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
11:45:21.222820 IP 212.199.xx.xxx.56486 > 192.168.30.120.80: Flags [.], ack 1, win 256, length 0
11:45:42.520396 IP 212.199.xx.xxx.56486 > 192.168.30.120.80: Flags [R.], seq 421, ack 1, win 0, length 0
11:45:42.520422 IP 192.168.30.120.80 > 212.199.xx.xxx.56486: Flags [.], ack 1, win 115, length 0
11:46:11.224424 IP 192.168.30.120.80 > 212.199.xx.xxx.56486: Flags [F.], seq 1:213, ack 1, win 115, length 212: HTTP: HTTP/1.0 408 Request Time-out
11:46:11.430474 IP 192.168.30.120.80 > 212.199.xx.xxx.56486: Flags [F.], seq 1:213, ack 1, win 115, length 212: HTTP: HTTP/1.0 408 Request Time-out
11:46:11.846588 IP 192.168.30.120.80 > 212.199.xx.xxx.56486: Flags [F.], seq 1:213, ack 1, win 115, length 212: HTTP: HTTP/1.0 408 Request Time-out
11:46:12.678507 IP 192.168.30.120.80 > 212.199.xx.xxx.56486: Flags [F.], seq 1:213, ack 1, win 115, length 212: HTTP: HTTP/1.0 408 Request Time-out
11:46:14.346492 IP 192.168.30.120.80 > 212.199.xx.xxx.56486: Flags [F.], seq 1:213, ack 1, win 115, length 212: HTTP: HTTP/1.0 408 Request Time-out
11:46:17.678470 IP 192.168.30.120.80 > 212.199.xx.xxx.56486: Flags [F.], seq 1:213, ack 1, win 115, length 212: HTTP: HTTP/1.0 408 Request Time-out
11:46:24.350533 IP 192.168.30.120.80 > 212.199.xx.xxx.56486: Flags [F.], seq 1:213, ack 1, win 115, length 212: HTTP: HTTP/1.0 408 Request Time-out
```

This is really all the information I managed to collect.

I'm pretty lost right now as I tried everything I could :X

Appreciating any help!

Thank you

Comment: Please provide your config and your tests directly in the post, properly formatted, without external services like pastebin. It's pretty hard to read right now.

Comment: Sorry, It's pretty long log so I decided to use pastebin..Fixing it now.

Comment: The 3-way looks successful, but in the gap before the inbound reset at 11:45:42.520396, it looks like there should have been data from the client, but the proxy saw nothing.  I would say this is not a problem with the HAProxy machine.  Capture packets on the client machine and compare, if possible.

Comment: Oh... and that is consistent with what HAProxy logged.  `cR--` decodes as *the client-side timeout expired while waiting for the client to send or receive data; the proxy was waiting for a complete, valid REQUEST from the client (HTTP mode only). Nothing was sent to any [backend] server.* 
http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#8.5